# Какой корень использовать: "ЛОЖ" или "КЛАД"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите какой правильно использовать корень "ЛОЖ" либо "КЛАД" в следующих предложениях: 
1) В бюджет 2024 года надо заложить параметры,которые позволят сделать повышение пенсий, выше показателей инфляции. 
2) За границей 2024 года пенсия также будет расти выше инфляции», — добавила Голикова. По ее словам, уровень пенсионного обеспечения, который заложат в рамках рассматриваемого закона, позволяет говорить, что пенсии будут увеличивать выше инфляции каждый год на долгосрочную перспективу.

Comment: Что значит "какой использовать корень"? Корень зависит от слова, которое вы хотите использовать. Нельзя использовать корень сам по себе.

Comment: Оффтоп, но на всякий случай: в предложении 1) запятая между словами "пенсий" и "выше" - лишняя.

Answer (score 1):

В обоих предложениях у вас глагол *совершенного* вида, поэтому правильно "**заложить/заложат**". Глагол с другим корнем - всегда *несовершенного* вида, например, в таком контексте:

> Параметры расходов всегда *закладывают* в бюджет с учётом инфляции.

Comment: Спор с преподавателем, который утверждает что слово заложить вообще использовать неверно, такого слова нет есть слово закладывать. помогите доказать правоту.

Comment: Сошлитесь на словарь Ушакова - есть такое слово: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/807358

Comment: Как это нет? Заложить имущество, заложило нос, заложить первый камень...